# Remove spaces between items returned in a list

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

If my understanding of the below code I have is correct Python is returning a list from a the source code of a web page that I am scraping (the data is not stored within any HTML tags, hence why I'm not using XPath or anything to scrape the data I want):

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
import re
import json

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal4"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com"]
    download_delay = 1

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(''),deny=('/News', '/Fixtures', '/Graphics', '/Articles', '/Live', '/Matches', '/Explanations', '/Glossary', '/Players', 'ContactUs', 'TermsOfUse'),), follow=False, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)

        match1 = re.search(re.escape("DataStore.prime('stage-player-stat', defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams.defaultParams , ") \
                     + '(\[.*\])' + re.escape(");"), response.body)

        if match1 is not None:
            playerdata1 = match1.group(1)

            for player in json.loads(playerdata1):

                player['Name'],',',player['FirstName'],',',player['LastName']
```

I've worked out how put a comma between the data elements I am printing, but this is printing with a space between each element and the comma, in the following fashion:

```
Name , FirstName , LastName
```

How can I get it so that it is printed like this instead:

```
Name,FirstName,LastName
```

Thanks

Comment: you can remove `\s*`

Comment: @Fede thanks for replying...you mean remove spaces from the regex?

Comment: perhaps you want the `csv` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
print("{Name},{FirstName},{LastName}".decode().format(**player)) # gets values of keys specified in format args from player
```

Comment: you don't even need rstrip; the spaces are coming solely from the print statement

Comment: @PadraicCunningham where do i use str.format in that above example. straight copying and pasting the code in your example gave the following error 'exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'' thanks

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, in some results there will be empty fields, but in others those fields will be populated

Comment: @PadraicCunningham for some it now works, but for others it errors with ' exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)'...using just simply print player['Name'], player['FirstName'] etc it ran without errors, but it printed a space between each part of the list

Comment: try `print("{Name},{FirstName},{LastName}".decode().format(**player))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes that seems to be working now, thanks a lot...hadnt factored in the accents and umlauts of continental europe (and ireland for that matter too!)...what does the '**player' part of above do?

Comment: basically we are using the keys of the dict as format arguments, and `**` is special syntax that basically gets the values from the dicts keys. it would be the same as doing `player['FirstName']`,just a nice more concise  way

Comment: @PadraicCunningham right ok. so that data being pulled in via json.load from the source code is that a list or dict to start with? it looks like a list to me. Are we then putting the values of that list into a dict with the above statement and then tweaking the format? thanks

Comment: @user3045351, no we are getting the values using the keys specified, if you print player, you will see. You are accessing it by key already in your own code, the format is just shorthand for that

Comment: @user3045351, no worries, you're welcome. How is your program going?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, it's coming along steadily, thanks...had to learn a lot starting from scratch which has taken time...i think they are cottoning in that it is a bot though now as i have started having it running really slow today and getting connection refused messages. i've been looking into using proxies, but im not sure how effective a counter-counter measure those would be. are there any common tricks other than using DOWNLOAD_DELAY to stop them getting on my back?

Comment: I am not too sure about that, do they not have any api or is there no similar site that does supply an api to get the data you need?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no there doesn't seem to be an API...someone has published a paper where they got data from the same place and their's was done in an almost identical way to mine (combination of xpath, regex and XHR request aping to get the data out).

Comment: I am surprised there is no easier way to get that kind of data, anyway time for sleep, happy scraping

Answer (score 3):

Simply `player['Name'] + ',' + player['FirstName'] + ',' + player['LastName']` will do what you want. The reason for this is that `,` concatenates `<space><string>` where `<space>` is whitespace and `<string>` is your string.